# VMware esxi bandwitch monitoring per VM

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-esxi

is there a way to monitor monthly bandwitch usage per VM on VMware ESXi. My server is in colocation and unfortunetly i can't use SNMP on virtual machines or network equipment to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - [vCenter](http://www.vmware.com/products/vcenter-server/) and/or [vRealize Business](http://www.vmware.com/products/vrealize-business/).

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't afford that (server is used only for non-profit educational purposes and i have to paid for bandwith usage). I was thinking about writing some kind of script, but i don't know how to find out how much traffic is used by each VM.

Comment: You must have skipped the bit in the text we make all new users read (or ignore) where we state that this site if for professional sysadmins, not learners.